# Internal Server Error: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<String:0x0000000589bde0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nitrousio

I hate to ask a question that looks like it's been asked so many times before, but my situation seems to be different. I'm using nitrous.io as my development environment, and when I try to preview my app, I get this error message.

The trace is:
    ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `symbolize_keys' for #<String:0x0000000476d9b0>

        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:327:in`secrets'
        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:461:in `validate_secret_key_config!'

        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:195:in`env_config'
        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:510:in `call'

        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/railties-4.1.8/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in`call'
        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'

        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in`call'
        /home/action/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'

        /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in`service'
        /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'

        /home/action/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in`block in start_thread'

I imagine there's a problem with my secret key, but I can't tell what it is. I don't even know what other information to put here!

If anyone has any kind of an idea, I'd appreciate your input . . .

Comment: As Finks mentioned somewhere you are passing a string when you should be passing a hash.  Can you post the format of your key (obviously don't post the key.)

Comment: try to generate a new secret with `rake secret`, then copy and paste to your `config/secrets.yml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPACE - your problem is a lack of a space char.

```
WRONG: secret_key_base:afcb44c
CORRECT: secret_key_base: afcb44c
```

check your config/secrets.yml, it should be something like that:

```
# Be sure to restart your server when you modify this file.

# Your secret key is used for verifying the integrity of signed cookies.
# If you change this key, all old signed cookies will become invalid!

# Make sure the secret is at least 30 characters and all random,
# no regular words or you'll be exposed to dictionary attacks.
# You can use `rake secret` to generate a secure secret key.

# Make sure the secrets in this file are kept private
# if you're sharing your code publicly.

production:
  secret_key_base: 59834597551c797b02cd5bb3edd7439f7a9c604bc82531d51d6e5f995e6ea849deb545df53213c5fd2ce4d698edfca65c8aa1b4e0fbadd884efefae0348b079b

development:
  secret_key_base: aea4705f645128e053daf1f8511014aca3b1e28323c3ece75f228540fb310869a6c4aeac172783d1c5c8ec9c5fe9b7f7af9a0204714db29e1d2a6709fca65ebf

test:
  secret_key_base: afcb44cfa8eab1f23d19b87e327d0fcc42e7c1d2c681812b346b57901ddb2511ebde569a1b868da367e2de14554c648f723a30de3daada015bbd0b268beeda3b

# Do not keep production secrets in the repository,
# instead read values from the environment.
# production:
#   secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

Also, if you need to generate new keys, do with the command: `rake secret`

So please, don't forget to add a space after ":".

Comment: The space made all the difference!

Answer (score 2):

`symbolize_keys` method is a method that expects the request to have a `Hash` data type, but you're request has a `string` instead. So check carefully your code.

Comment: It's the main reason for such errors - it's not a case specific - great job dude